# Can we hide / block access standard objects from some specific profile / users

Tags: standard-objects, object

If this is possible, what's the way to do it?

Comment: Hi Saikat - please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. In particular, you need to demonstrate some research, then use [edit]

Comment: In general, the answer to your question is "Yes" but I don't know if that's helpful to you. What objects do you want to prevent a user from accessing?

Answer (score 1):

For Custom Profiles, you simply uncheck the (Object) Read permission (e.g. "Account Read"). For Standard Profiles, you cannot remove access to Standard Objects. You must first clone a Standard Profile, remove any permissions you need to, and then assign to the users you want to restrict.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox. let me explain the scenario. I have cloned an administrator profile named 'cloneadmin' and create a new user guest user with that profile. now, from object access settings, I set no access to 'Accounts' Object and it is showing no access with that profile. Also set 'Default Off'.  But when I logged in with guest user login/pass from another browser, opened Sales App and I can see the Accounts tab and able to access the records also. How this is happening when I already set no access to the Accounts object with cloneadmin profile?

Comment: @SaikatMukhopadhyay Administrators have extra permissions, like Modify All Data, that you may need to remove as well. I would have started from cloning a [minimum access profile](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_general_new_profile.htm&type=5&release=226) and use permission sets, instead.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox. you are right. I created a new standard profile and assigned my previous user. I also followed the same previous steps and now I am not able to see the Accounts tab and any data related to Accounts. Thanks for all your help to understand the concept.